# Ошибка name 'txtSize' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, numpy

Исправьте ошибки. Пишет ошибку:

```
  line 10 in <module>
    digits_img = np.zeros((txtSize[1] + 7, txtSize[0]), np.uint8
                           ^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'txtSize' is not defined
```

Код:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

# Функция для распознавания чисел на изображении
def recognize_numbers(img):
    txtSize, baseline = cv2.getTextSize('0123456789', cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3, 5)
                                                                                # creating an image of size txt_Size
digits_img = np.zeros((txtSize[1] + 7, txtSize[0]), np.uint8)
cv2.putText(digits_img, '0123456789', (0, txtSize[1] + 2), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3, (255, 255, 255), 5)

cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(digits_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cnts.sort(key=lambda c: cv2.boundingRect(c)[0])

digits = []

for c in cnts:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    digits.append(digits_img[y:y + h, x:x + w])


def detect(img):                                                        #the draw
    elem = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (6, 6), (3, 3))
    dilat = cv2.dilate(img, elem, iterations=3)
                                                                        # find the drawed digit
    cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilat, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnts[0])
    roi = dilat[y:y + h, x:x + w]
                                                                        # find the best match
    percent_white_pix = 0
    digit = -1
    for i, d in enumerate(digits):
        scaled_roi = cv2.resize(roi, d.shape[:2][::-1])
        bitwise = cv2.bitwise_and(d, cv2.bitwise_xor(scaled_roi, d))
                                                                        # match is given by the highest loss of white pixel
        before = np.sum(d == 255)
        matching = 100 - (np.sum(bitwise == 255) / before * 100)
        if percent_white_pix < matching:
            percent_white_pix = matching
            digit = i

    return digit
''' Drawing on screen using pointer '''
drawing = False                                                         #mouse is pressed
pt1_x, pt1_y = None, None
# mouse callback function
def line_drawing(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global pt1_x, pt1_y, drawing

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        pt1_x, pt1_y = x, y
        cv2.rectangle(img, (0, 0, 512, 512), (0, 0, 0), -1)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing == True:
            cv2.line(img, (pt1_x, pt1_y), (x, y), color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=3)
            pt1_x, pt1_y = x, y
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
        cv2.line(img, (pt1_x, pt1_y), (x, y), color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=3)
        digit = detect(img)

        cv2.putText(img, 'It is a %d' % digit, (0, 40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)

img = np.zeros((360, 512, 1), np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('test draw')
cv2.setMouseCallback('test draw', line_drawing)

while (1):
    cv2.imshow('test draw', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

''' End drawing '''
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    # ... ваш существующий код для распознавания ...

# Функция для обработки выбранного изображения
def process_image():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('Image files', '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png')])  # Диалоговое окно выбора файла
    if file_path:
        img = cv2.imread(file_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Загрузка изображения в оттенках серого
        digit = recognize_numbers(img)  # Распознавание числа на изображении
        result_text = 'It is a %d' % digit
        result_label.configure(text=result_text)  # Отображение результата на метке

# Создание окна приложения
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Handwritten Number Recognition")
window.geometry("400x200")

# Кнопка для выбора изображения
select_button = tk.Button(window, text="Select Image", command=process_image)
select_button.pack(pady=10)

# Метка для отображения результата
result_label = tk.Label(window, text="")
result_label.pack()

# Запуск главного цикла приложения
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Скорее всего строки после `txtSize, baseline = cv2.getTextSize('0123456789', cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3, 5)` нужно внести в функцию `recognize_numbers`

Answer (score 0):

`text_Size` локальная переменная, то есть она существует только внутри функции. Для исправления нужно использовать глобальную переменную. Таким образом, этот пример вызовет ошибку:

```
def a()
   b=4444
a()
print(b) #error
```

А этот нет:

```
b=''
def a()
  global b
  b=555
a()
print(b) #555
```

Comment: Даже если сделать ее глобальной, это автору вопроса не поможет, т.к. у него функция recognize_numbers не вызывается на верхнем уровне (и не должна).